# User not getting emails of forget password in magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: magento-1.9, email

User is not getting emails of forget password in magento 1.9.0.1.While other mails are getting . Any body know the solution for this problem please share .

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

Check `System -> Configuration - > Customer -> Customer Configuration - > Password Option -> Forget email template` is there or not if it's there check **transaction mail** it load content or empty

To load email template follow the following steps.

1) Navigate to **System->Transactional Emails.**

2) Click on Add New Template button.

3) Under Load default template group for Template select **Forgot Password**

4) For Locale select your language and click on load template button.

You will be able to see content if their in Template Content area.

Comment: its not working and all setting are already there

Comment: go to System->Transactional Emails and load Forgot Password template ehat it showing